# Is it possible to respond to AJAX calls with out using "express" framework in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

Is it possible to respond to AJAX calls with out using  "express"  framework in Node.js??If so,how would you respond to an AJAX call made by for example, an  XMLHttpRequest() object

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you add more detail to your question please? What exactly are you trying to achieve with your application.

Comment: I am trying to send an AJAX request from the client side using a XMLHttpRequest  object .for example.                                                                                                                         let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', '/article/xmlhttprequest/example/load');                                                         **naw, I want to know if it is possible to reply to this AJAX call using a node.js server but  with out using express.If yes,then how would you do it.(I'm new to programming and I really appreciate your help :))

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  You can write your own web server using the `http` or `https` modules directly.  Here's a very basic server.

```
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    // all incoming http requests to your server will arrive here
    console.log(req.url);
    res.end("hi");
});
server.listen(80);
```

Of course, the reason that Express exists and that a lot of people use it is that it makes a lot of things that one might normally do in a web server a lot simpler than coding those things yourself with a plain http server and it gives you access to a ready made library of middleware on NPM (for things like session management, authentication, mime parsing, uploads, etc...).  But, nobody requires you to use the higher level framework.  You can code that stuff yourself if you want to.

Of course, if you really wanted to get down to the lowest level, you could even write your own http server using only the Net module, but then you'd be writing code for the http protocol too.

Comment: I'd expect this to throw an error trying to bind itself to port 80.

Comment: @AndrewDibble - Works just fine on my Windows system.  It depends upon your OS and the privileges you run the code with.  That is, however, not particularly germaine to the question as this is no different whether running Express or not.  One is free to pick whatever port number is appropriate for your situation.